# Using Vuex with Nuxt.js - The right way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I try to add Vuex to my Nuxt.js project. I made a custom ligthbox and to share through all pages I write the code into the default layout page.

From a page, to hide or show the ligthbox I need to change the state value. This is all the modules into the "store" folder:

```js
// state.js
export const state = () => ({
    lightbox: false,
});
```

```js
// getters.js
export const getters = {
    getLightbox(state)
    {
        return state.lightbox
    },
}
```

```js
// actions.js
export const actions = {
    showLightbox({commit})
    {
        commit('UPDATE_LIGHTBOX', true)
    },
    hideLightbox({commit})
    {
        commit('UPDATE_LIGHTBOX', false)
    },
}
```

```js
// mutations.js
export const mutations = {
    UPDATE_LIGHTBOX(state,value)
    {
        state.lightbox = value
    },
}
```

Then when I try to call "this.$store.state.lightbox" from a method I get an 500 error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
```

Even I try to use this way and I get the same error:

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getLightbox']),
        lightboxState()
        {
            return this.getLightbox
        },
    }
    mounted()
    {
        console.log( this.lightboxState )
    }
}
```

Later I try with asyncData but the console print an "undefined" value:

```js
export default {
    asyncData({ store })
    {
        console.log('Store =',store);
    }
}
```

So, what is the right way to using Vuex with Nuxt.js? Maybe I need to add something else to "nuxt.config.js"?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using separate files for `state.js`, `getters.js`, `mutations.js` and `actions.js`, they should only have a single, default export.

So instead of

```js
// getters.js
export const getters = ...
```

you should use

```js
// getters.js
export default {
  getLightbox: state => state.lightbox
}
```

This applies to all the files in your `store` directory.

See https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#modules-mode

Comment: +Phil Thank you but even I replace it with "export default" and the state I replace it with "export default ()", I get the same 500 error. Printing the "store" in asyncData I get an undefined value. Sorry.